# Jersey can not handle big data

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) to send a GET request:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);
ClientResponse res = webResource.queryParams(params).get(ClientResponse.class);

//hangs out forever if uri returns big data(maybe > 2Mb, since those code run normally with about 1Mb data)
String result = res.getEntity(String.class);
```

The application is running on Tomcat 7.
Do I need to config anything?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that its a problem with Jersey and not with the server itself? have you made a manual request to the service? (via curl or browser)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a byte limit depending on web server as well as from the browser.
See here :-

[maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

There is no size limit in http protocol but their is size limit imposed by server.
For response size limit it is very clearly mentioned in Tomcat 7 official documentation here:-

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: The question is about the response not the request

Comment: Could you point out the configuration option controlling a response size limit in your answer?